# kindly check is this code is fine

Tags: apex

```
public class Prime {
    Integer i,num;
    public void entnum(Integer n){
        num = n;
        for (i=2;   i<=num; i++){
            if (system.math.mod(num,i) == 0){
                System.debug('Number is not Prime');
                break;
            }
                if(i == num) {
                  system.debug('Number is  Prime');  

                } 
            }
        }
       }
```

Comment: Hi @VikramSingh, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Hopefully you are aware that this is the [most basic algorithm](https://dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-determine-if) really only suited to small values on n. Normally such a method would return a boolean and use local variables only.

Comment: What do you mean by fine? Do you want us to make a code review?

Comment: hI ! all  every time it gives output that "number is not prime " .

Comment: well, problem is that as soon as i equals num, it falls into first if (because math.mod(a,a) == 0 always), so it returns Number is not prime

Comment: Hi Vikram, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. The things that made this post off topic were its exceedingly vague title and your complete lack of a description inside the post (it's just a code dump). In the future, please take some time *within your post body* to explain what you are trying to achieve, and why the code you have doesn't fit your needs. Also, please try to make a title  which indicates the topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if integer number is prime

```
public static Boolean isPrime(Integer n) {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n != 2 && Math.mod(n, 2) == 0) return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for(Integer i=3; i*i<=n; i+=2) {
        if(Math.mod(n, i) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 2 is also a prime number, in your example it will return false for n=2.

Comment: @Poster yes, you are right. I've updated my post with one more condition

Comment: Didn't realize the side effects of voting to close with that particular reason...sorry this got deleted. :(